# How to secure a client-server internet based connection?

Tags: c#, client

I am using VS2010 - C#

I want to build an exchange rate monitor that has a client and a server applications.

The clients get to see the values sent by the server.

I know all the steps to create such a thing but my question is :

What is someone managed to steal the data while its being sent from the server to the client ? how do you recommend protecting it from theft ?

any suggestions . . .

Comment: Encryption / SSL? Without knowing how you want to secure it, it's hard to answer the question.

Comment: can I install SSL on a C# server app. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (formerly SSL) to prevent eavesdropping or tampering. Additionally, if you want your clients to authenticate, you can issue client certificates and require them upon connection.

To create client certificates you need to create your own local root certificate (to become what is known as a Certificate Authority (CA)), and then issue a server certificate and client certificates using that CA certificate. I advise you to read a book on TLS/SSL to fully understand these certificates, how they relate, and how they are used by TLS.

The most relevant class to read up on if you are implementing this using .NET is [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). The relevant method for client certificate authentication is [AuthenticateAsClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145061.aspx).

Comment: can you tell me alittle bit more about this client certificates thing ?

Comment: Answer updated. This is a big topic, so my best advice is to read a book on it if you are not already familiar with it.

Comment: You can also use a Username/Password authentication. Certificates usually used in B2B communication. If a user uses the client application is better to use Username/Password.

Answer (score 0):

if you're worried about sniffers, this is a solved provlem.

http://www.openssl.org/